# Error trying to stub function with mockito python with generic arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, mockito, typeerror, stubbing

I have been having a look and cannot see anyone with the same issue as me in Python.

I may well be being very daft here, but I am trying to stub out a method that takes several arguments.  Within my test I just want to return a value regardless of the arguments (i.e. for every call just return the same value).  Therefore I have have been trying to use 'generic' arguments, but I am clearly doing something wrong.

Can anyone spot my issue?

```
from mockito import mock, when

class MyClass():

    def myfunction(self, list1, list2, str1, str2):
        #some logic
        return []


def testedFunction(myClass):
    # Logic I actually want to test but in this example who cares...
     return myClass.myfunction(["foo", "bar"], [1,2,3], "string1", "string2")

mockReturn = [ "a", "b", "c" ]

myMock = mock(MyClass)
when(myMock).myfunction(any(list), any(list), any(str), any(str)).thenReturn(mockReturn)

results = testedFunction(myMock)

# Assert the test
```

I have managed to replicate my issue in the above very basic code. Here I just want to stub out MyClass.myfunction for any set of arguments.  If I leave the arguments out - i.e:

```
when(myMock).myfunction().thenReturn(mockReturn)
```

then nothing is returned whatsoever (so the stubbing isn't working).  However with the 'generic arguments' the following error:

```
     when(myMock).myfunction(any(list), any(list), any(str), any(str)).thenReturn(mockReturn)
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

I know I must be doing something stupid, as I used to do this all the time in Java but can't think what I am doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`any` in this case is [the built-in `any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any), which expects an iterable of some kind and returns `True` if any of the elements in the iterable are truthy.  You need to explicitly import `matchers.any`:

```
from mockito.matchers import any as ANY

when(myMock).myfunction(ANY(list), ANY(list), ANY(str), ANY(str)).thenReturn(mockReturn)
```

Comment: Sean, you are a star, spot on.  Thanks a bunch.